# How to convert "svyrep.design"’ to a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, survey

I'd like to convert a svyrep.design / survey.design object in R into a data frame.  I'm aware that this object would be quite large.

```
library(survey)
data(api)   # loads "apiclus2" sample data
dclus2 <- svydesign(id=~dnum+snum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus2)
```

The above applies weights a data frame, turning it into a survey object.

```
dclus2  =  as.data.frame(dclus2)
```

Error message:

```
# Error in as.data.frame.default(dclus2) : 
# cannot coerce class ‘c("survey.design2", "survey.design")’ to a data.frame`
```

I'd like to turn it back into a data frame, with the weights now applied to the object. But as you can see above, this is not possible via "as.data.frame".

Comment: The above example has been edited to be easily/fully reproduced.

Comment: I still am not sure what "back into a data.frame" means in this case. What exactly does the desired output look like in this case?

Comment: It would just be a data frame, but with the weights applied to the object. I cleaned things up a bit to hopefully make things clearer.

Comment: I mean, what would that look like for a categorical column? The survey package has methods to calculate statistics given a survey design, but it's not clear how you would apply these weights directly to a "raw" data.frame.

Comment: Ideally, it'd be an individual entry for post-weighted survey.  So if it was a 60K respondent representative sample of the USA, then it'd now have 330m rows.

Comment: You should look at the output of `str(dclus2)` and then specify which of the several list items should be chosen to include in the desired dataframe. `names(dclus2)` returns: `[1] "cluster"    "strata"     "has.strata" "prob"       "allprob"    "call"       "variables"  "fpc"        "pps"`, but not all of those list items have dimension that are congruent with the dimension of the original data. You should also specifiy mathematically what is meant by having "the weights now applied to the object".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you're looking to do something like this?  your example has decimal points in the weights, but you can't have half a record.  in the final result `x` data.frame, the number of records equals sum of the rounded weights from the original survey data.frame.  when you make this conversion, the final data set wouldn't be useful for estimates of uncertainty

```
library(survey)
data(api)
apiclus2$rounded_weights <- round( apiclus2$pw )
x <- apiclus2[ unlist( mapply( rep , seq( nrow( apiclus2 ) ) , apiclus2$rounded_weights ) ) , ]
sum( apiclus2$rounded_weights ) == nrow( x )
```